# IMX7D Sabre Yocto Project with OP-TEE examples

Tags: yocto, imx7, op-tee

First time I am trying to create SD-Card Linux image for imx7d sabre with OP-TEE using Yocto. I followed this document https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/i.MX_Yocto_Project_User's_Guide_Linux.pdf for building the image. I was able to build the image with OP-TEE and successfully run the OP-TEE Xtest. But now I do not know how to run OP-TEE examples in the image. These binaries are not present in the bin folder

Questions

1. How to include OP-TEE examples to Yocto
2. In future how to add my own trusted applications to Yocto.

   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to include OP-TEE examples to Yocto

Add to your `local.conf`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " optee-examples"
```

> In future how to add my own trusted applications to Yocto.

Create a recipe based on `recipes-security/optee/optee-examples.bb` and add it to the image as stated above.